# How to test non-serializable code in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a spark code which sends requests to DynamoDB. The [AmazonDynamoDBClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html)  which is used to make connection with database is not serializable.

So I'm making instance of this class within `mapPartition` method in Scala like this ->

```
recordsToWrite.mapPartitions { iter =>
  var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccess, awsSecret)
  var client= new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials)
  var dynamoDB=new DynamoDB(client)
  var optTable=dynamoDB.getTable(tableName)
  iter.map { x => 
    //some code....
    optTable.updateItem(x)
  }
}
```

The problem is I want to test this code with local spark (spark-testing-base) and dynamodb in unit test.

I can not take `AmazonDynamoDBClient` out of `mapPartition` since its not serializable (Exception is thrown by spark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `DynamoDBFactory` trait which *is* serializable, with two implementations, a "real" one and a "test" one (I'm assuming the issue is how to "inject" a test client):

```
trait DynamoDBFactory extends Serializable {
  def createClient(awsAccess: String, awsSecret: String): DynamoDB
}

class RealDynamoDBFactory extends DynamoDBFactory {
  def createClient(awsAccess: String, awsSecret: String): DynamoDB = {
    var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccess, awsSecret)
    var client= new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials)
    new DynamoDB(client)
  }
}

class TestDynamoDBFactory extends DynamoDBFactory {
  def createClient(awsAccess: String, awsSecret: String): DynamoDB = {
    // return your test stub / mock / whatever you need
  }
}
```

And then, have your tested code expect an instance of `DynamoDBFactory` and pass the right instance in tests/production code:

```
val dynamoDBFactory: DynamoDBFactory = // ...get it from caller
recordsToWrite.mapPartitions { iter =>
  var dynamoDB = dynamoDBFactory.createClient(awsAccess, awsSecret)
  var optTable=dynamoDB.getTable(tableName)
  iter.map { x => 
    //some code....
    optTable.updateItem(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: Had to do minor modifications, but it worked. Thanks :)